# Send data from UISearchBar to jQuery

Tags: jquery, ios, swift, webkit, uisearchbar

I have a `WKWebView` that is displaying `index.html` which runs `demo.js`.

The index page just displays an HTML form where the user can put in a character, but I need to replace this with a UISearchBar.

Currently in jQuery (when document is ready), I have:

```
$('.js-char-form').on('submit', function(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
     updateCharacter(); // does something important
});
```

How might I approach this problem with a UISearchBar instead?

Am I misusing jQuery here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view controller, you will need a function for when the search bar is clicked.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder() // hide keyboard
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("changeCharacter('\(searchBar.text ?? "alternative character")')") { (result, error) in
        if error == nil {
            // success, do nothing...
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the demo.js, you would have

```
function changeCharacter(newCharacter) {
    // do something with newCharacter...
}
```

In essence, all this does is run a JavaScript function but replace the parameter with something defined in the Swift context.

Additionally, if you'd like to hide the keyboard after the searchbar has been used, you can use an extension. So, in the view controller again, you'd write:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```